# HTML tags getting nested

Tags: android, html, android-edittext

I am creating a rich text editor. The requirement is that, the user will use the editor in a edittext. Once the user completes editing the text, the html content of the edittext will e gathered and posted to the server. The edittexts' styles should be posted to the server.

I have implemented the formatting in the rich text editor edittext like this:

```
mainEditText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable spanTest) {
        boldBtn = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.boldBtn);
        italicBtn = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.italicBtn);
        underLineBtn = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.underLineBtn);

        // http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/Selection.html

        // Runa toast for the selector index

        // http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ClipboardManager.html

        try {
            int selectionStart = Math.max(mainEditText.getSelectionStart(), 0);

            int position = Selection.getSelectionStart(mainEditText.getText());
            if (position < 0) {
                position = 0;
            }
            if (position > 0) {

                if (selectionStart > position || position > (cursorLoc + 1)) {
                    // user changed cursor location, reset
                    selectionStart = position - 1;
                }
                cursorLoc = position;
                if (boldBtn.isChecked()) {
                    // edited to make texteditor bug free
                    if (cursorLoc >= styleStart) {
                        spanTest.setSpan(new StyleSpan(android.graphics.Typeface.BOLD), styleStart, position, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
                        Log.e("Html span: " , Html.toHtml(spanTest));
                    } else {}

                }

                if (italicBtn.isChecked()) {
                    // edited to make texteditor bug free
                    if (cursorLoc >= styleStart) {
                        spanTest.setSpan(new StyleSpan(android.graphics.Typeface.ITALIC), styleStart, position, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
                    } else {}

                }

                if (underLineBtn.isChecked()) {
                    //edited to make texteditor bug free
                    if (cursorLoc >= styleStart) {
                        spanTest.setSpan(new UnderlineSpan(), styleStart, position, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
                    } else {}
                }

            }
        } catch (IndexOutOfBoundsException varName) {}
    }

    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

        // testClipboard();
    }

    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
        int startSelection = Selection.getSelectionStart(s);
        int endSelection = Selection.getSelectionEnd(s);

    }
});
```

This is how I am checking the text before sending it to the server:

```
String htmlString=Html.toHtml(mainEditText.getText());
        makeAToast(htmlString);
        Log.d("htmlString", htmlString);
```

The html which is getting generated is having nested tags:

```
<p dir="ltr">hello boys <b><b><b><b><b><b><b><b><b>n</b></b></b></b></b></b></b></b></b><b><b><b><b><b><b><b><b>o</b></b></b></b></b></b></b></b><b><b><b><b><b><b><b>w</b></b></b></b></b></b></b><b><b><b><b><b><b> </b></b></b></b></b></b><b><b><b><b><b>b</b></b></b></b></b><b><b><b><b>o</b></b></b></b><b><b><b>l</b></b></b><b><b>d</b></b><b> </b></p>
```

Where am I doing wrong? What is it that should be tweaked to generate a proper html before sending it to the server?

Comment: Can you try using TextView.clearComposingText() before you do getText()?

Comment: @Rohan where do you actually want me to put it?

Comment: Before getting the text to send to server: mainEditText.clearComposingText(); then call mainEditText.getText()

Comment: @Rohan mainEditText.clearComposingText();
  String htmlString=Html.toHtml(mainEditText.getText()); output is same

Comment: @Unihedron suggestions?

Comment: Then the problem is around the way we are adding spans to the Editable. Try keying in a single character in your edit text and see how many spans are getting added. If it is showing multiple style spans per style, you need to add checks in the above code that if the style is already applied to the current selection, do not add a new style span for it.

Comment: @Rohan I am trying to achieve the same but am unable to do so

Answer (score 0):

Since multiple `StyleSpan` are being added for the same style, it is better to check if the same span is already applied to your selection.

```
// get existing spans on selection
StyleSpan[] existingSpans = spanTest.getSpans (editText.getSelectionStart(), editText.getSelectionEnd(), StyleSpan.class);

boolean styleExists = false;
int yourStyle = Typeface.BOLD; // add your button logic here to get the appropriate style

foreach (StyleSpan span : existingSpans)
{
    if (span.getStyle() == yourStyle)
    {
        styleExists = true;
        break;
    }
}

if (!styleExists)
{
    spanTest.setSpan (new StyleSpan (yourStyle, editText.getSelectionStart(), editText.getSelectionEnd(), Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
}
else
{
    // do nothing as a span with same style already exists.
}
```

Comment: Editable is spanTest in your case. Did you try this out?

Comment: foreach (StyleSpan span : existingSpans) is showing an error saying StyleSpan cannot be resolved to a variable. What should be done?

Comment: int yourStyle = boldBtn.isChecked(); has an error saying Type mismatch: cannot convert from boolean to int

Comment: The code above is not to be compiled verbatim! Its there to give you an idea how to go about it. You need to set yourStyle to Typeface.BOLD or others as per the buttons checked. Add required imports for StyleSpan.